# powershell how to force array to read line by line , instead of character by character

Tags: arrays, powershell

So I have a file which is an external variable. 
I use a PowerShell script to read it into an array to further process each line.

However, sometimes if the file has only one line, then the array will automatically read the file character-by-character.

Example - input file with only one row:

> U09

Code:

```
$file = get-content $INPUT FILE
Write-Host $file[0]
```

Then I get the result `U` instead of `U09`

How do  I avoid this?

Comment: `$file = @(get-content $INPUT_FILE)` - wrap in `@()` to force it to be an array even when there's only one line

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Nice. Please consider posting as answer so this can be marked as answered and removed from unanswered queue.

Comment: @gms0ulman It's a common powershell question, I was sure it was a duplicate, but couldn't find one quickly at the time. I've found one now and voted for it to be a dupe of that one instead of answering here.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  just tried. perfect. thank you very much!